# Bash Script: IP Address variable's possible?

Tags: linux, bash, networking

Is it at all possible to make an IP Address point to a specific name? I don't mind what method needs to be done, just need some suggestions as I'm new to bash. The reason for this is I want to make a script that checks which Site the IP I input is for.

e.g 10.10.100.10 = SITECODE

Comment: You can set static ip to host entries in [/etc/hosts](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html). Though it's not entirely clear that's really what you are after.

Comment: But.. bash is not responsible for translating ip to a name, it's unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here is a working code, $1 is for the first argument after the script name in the console command.

P.S. I have bash 4.4.20 version

you can run it  like this:

> ./script.sh 127.0.0.1

the output should be:

> Alice

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$1
ARRAY=( "127.0.0.1:Alice"
        "127.0.0.2:Bob"
        "127.0.0.3:John"
         )

for pair in "${ARRAY[@]}" ; do
KEY="${pair%%:*}"
if [ "$KEY" = "$INPUT" ];then
    VALUE="${pair##*:}"
    echo $VALUE    
fi
done
```

another variant is to read from file list_of_ip.txt (the file should not have additional newline):

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$1

while IFS= read -r pair; do
    KEY="${pair%%:*}"
    if [ "$KEY" = "$INPUT" ];then
        VALUE="${pair##*:}"
        echo $VALUE
    fi
done < list_of_ip.txt
```

Comment: Why would you use a numerically-indexed array rather than an associative one (where the keys used to index into it are themselves strings)? If you have `declare -A array=( ["127.0.0.1"]="Alice" ["127.0.0.2"]="Bob" )`, you can just look up `${array[127.0.0.1]}` in constant time to get `Alice` as a result.

Comment: And `[ $KEY == $INPUT ]` is several flavors of wrong -- it'll behave badly if your IFS value contains characters found in either of your variables, or if that variable is empty. Quote your strings, and for best portability use `=` (the POSIX-specified `test` operator for string comparison) instead of `==` (a bash extension). Thus: `[ "$KEY" = "$INPUT" ]`

Comment: ...and also consider using lower-case names for _all_ your variables, not just `pair`. POSIX specifies that all-uppercase variables are allowed to modify behavior of your shell or other operating-system-provided tools, whereas variables with at least one lower-case letter in their names are guaranteed not to modify behavior of the shell or POSIX-specified OS-provided tools (see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a single namespace).

Comment: I think you contradict yourself a little bit, on another system there may be another version of Bash that does not support Hash tables.

Comment: I recommend against using nonportable constructs _when they add no value_. `==` adds no benefit whatsoever; you're writing longer code than you would with `=`, and also getting code that doesn't work on baseline POSIX `test`. Hash tables / associative arrays _do_ add a benefit (in both terseness and performance), so you get something in return for paying the cost of nonportable code.

Comment: `==` can be considered as "syntactic sugar" from a lot of perspectives.

Comment: Thank you both. Using arrays to achieve this solved it.